# How distribute specific iOS app version for specific region/territory

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store, app-distribution

I have published app not for all the world.
I want to add one more region but for this region I want to push specific version with additional changes and other internal settings.
I know how to manage full access of the app. But what about concrete version? Should I register one more app and distribute it only for this territory?

**Example:**

I have a version 0.0.15.4 that was published at the store for example for Germany region.
Now I have prepared version 0.0.16.12 and I want to share it to China, only for China region.
In result I want to have two versions one for Germany (0.0.15.4) and the next one for China (0.0.16.12). They both should be available from that stores. Why? Because they use different server urls (China government restrictions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: **No**

Answer from Apple Developer Program Support:
**At this time, your app may only have one build available on the App Store at any given time.** If you were to update the region of availability to only be accessible on the App Store in China for version 0.0.15, version 0.0.16 would not be able to exist simultaneously on the App Store in Germany.

Comment: I have an app. I have pushed my app store for US region. Now I need to add German as well. Can I able to do this by editing or doing something in my apple account.

Comment: Hi @sejn. Yes, you can. You need to add a new region at the appstoreconnect and release a new version (build). The app should be checked again by Apple. After that, your app will appear in the Germany region.